# I can't update any apps in Google play store

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Why I can't update any apps and it keeps on saying that I have insufficient storage but I think its not the problem because I have storage. So what should I do?

Comment: You should give more information.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need at least 10 percent of your whole data storage to install applications.

You should delete some stuff or clean up the cache by going into Settings -> Storage -> Cache

If that does not help, clear the data of Google Play Store using Settings -> Applications (or Settings -> Storage -> Apps) and then swiping to the left until you get to `All applications` and  then search for Google Play Store and delete the data. Then start Play Store again and try it out if it works.